# Consequences of the PermGen suppression

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, java-8

The [next java release](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/) comes with the [removal of the permanent generation](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/122) from the Hotspot JVM. What are the consequences a java developer should know ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JEP you linked:

> > Moving interned Strings and class statics to the Java heap may result in an Out-of-memory exception or an increase in the number of GCs.

That's one of the major consequences I can think of. Your applications could try to load new classes and thus trigger a GC or even get an OOME because there's no explicit memory area which is reserved for such data. Some applications might be able to recover from an OOME but I'm not sure this is true when it is thrown during class loading, especially for legacy applications that were built with PermGen in mind.

On the other hand, it would be nice not to have to configure PermGen explicitly, especially if a larger portion is not needed. This also might make GCing the data in PermGen easier and reduce the risk of those dreaded PermGen space errors.

However, if there are memory leaks, removing the PermGen would probably only make it harder to track them. If classes cannot be unloaded for some reason (like in older jboss versions) it would make not much difference which memory portion is blocked. The leak would still exist, it might just become obvious a bit later, since there are less hard restrictions.

That's just my 2 cents and I might be completely wrong here, but those are the implications I can currently think of.